# DATE - Normalization, a multiple ranged query, multiple inserts and multiple update

Tags: database-design, schema, normalization, date

I have a booking system, airbnb style.

**TABLES -> prices, house, available_date**

A house has available days and not available days, but sometimes the days have different prices. A weekend is more expensive for example.

What are my options for storing the days: available, not available? If a house can have up to 366 information days....

First alternative was to build **columns** with the information **startSaleDate**, **endSaleDate**. What in my opinion may be a choice of low performance of search. Because, when a day in the range is sale, we have to reprogram the house row, and have a possibility to be available a day on, a day off, generating 366 rows for 1 house!

### Are there other alternatives? Like normalization of dates, or algorithms?

I'm not really finding anything that might help me with the mentioned problem...

Comment: Can you give more information about the datamodel (maybe SQL code?) you currently have? It does not have to be perfect, but I'm lacking information to provide you with a proper answer.